# How to create a daily slideshow in PHP/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, slideshow

I have a folder of images and I want to show one image per day (say change at 8am each day) using php/javascript. There are 21 images in all (21 days worth) and then loop around again.

Is there a function, which will just call the next image after a certain amount of time?

or can be it be some sort of increment?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

```
$images = scandir("/my/images/path"); //puts all images into a 0-indexed array
$day = date('j',strtotime("-8 hours")) - 1; //get todays day - 0-30
$todays_key = $day%20; //use remainder function to make sure the key is between 0 and 20
$todays_image = $images[$todays_key]; //use the key to get the image
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard each line is commented with an explanation

Comment: Ah, "self-documenting" answer.

Comment: Sorry this piece of code doesn't really make much sense

Comment: @CraigStanley which part of it doesn't make sense? Do you understand the 1st line? If not, read the documentation for `scandir` at php.net and put `var_dump($images)` after the 1st line. Repeat for the next lines. If you have a specific question I'll be glad to answer it.